# Use value from httpClient after completion

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular (9) project I fetch some values with `HttpClient` from a Rest-API. I subscribe it at different places (mostly with `async` pipe, not directly but anyway). To make it multicast, I "wrap" the result of the HTTP-service in a `BahaviorSubject`:

```ts
const loadingDog = new BehaviorSubject<Dog|boolean>(true);
const subscription = this.getDogFromHttpClient(dogName)
   .pipe(map((dog: Dog|boolean) => this.someProecessing(dog)))
   .subscribe(loadingDog);
return loadingDog;
```

I could also have uses `share` I guess.

Dogs never change. So, to avoid duplicate calls to static content store the `loadingDog`-Subjects in an array and, if dog is allready fetched return the stored Subject from the array.

```ts
public dogs: BehaviorSubject<Dog|boolean>[] = [];

public getDog(name: string): BehaviorSubject<Dog|boolean> {

    if (isDefined(this.dogs[dogName])) {

        return this.dogs[dogName];
    }

   const loadingDog = new BehaviorSubject<Dog|boolean>(true);
   const subscription = this.http
          .get<Dog>(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${dogName}/images`)
          .pipe(map((dog: Dog|boolean) => this.someProcessing(dog)))
          .subscribe(loadingDog);

   this.dogs[dogName] = loadingDog;

   return loadingDog;
}
```

And in the different components I use it like this:

```ts
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.useMeInTemplate$ = dogService.getDog('akita').asObservable();
  }
```

So the component can decide if it want to display a loading-sign, or (in most cases) if observable is already fulfilled, the content. Works fine. I display the same dog in many components. Every subscription get triggered at least once, with the Dog's content or if very fast, twice, with loading state (`true` in my example) and then the content.

But if I want to create a new one later and re-use the observable, it does not work. The reason seems to be, that the HttpClient completes the Observable at one point, and thus the wrapping BehaviorSubject gets completed as well.

[I have created an example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ianx2f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), where I put everything in one component. Click on the div to see it not working ;)

I guess, my wrapping of the httpClient might be done wrong. Or I might have a bigger conceptual misconception of how to "cache" the httpResults? Or can I and have to avoid the completion of the Subject? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `shareReplay(1)`, then every time when someone subscribes they'll get the latest known response.

Something like that.

```js
public dogs = new Map<string, Observable<Dog|boolean>>();

public getDog(name: string): Observable<Dog|boolean> {
  if (!this.dogs.has(name)) {
    this.dogs.set(dogName, this.http
      .get<Dog|boolean>(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${name}/images`)
      .pipe(
        map(dog => this.someProcessing(dog)),
        shareReplay(1),
      ),
    );
  }
  return this.dogs.get(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually works in the example. I thought since I could obtain the the last value everytime from the BehaviorSubject with `getValue()`, even after completion, BehaviorSubject is the right way to go... I will try this in the real code, but I guess, this already the answer.

Comment: It's quite similar to what you describe, `shareReplay` uses `ReplaySubject` behind and it also respects `completion`.

Comment: One thing which confuses me a lot is, when it used `ReplaySubject` why is the return of your getDog-function an simple Observable, not `ReplaySubject`?

Comment: `ReplaySubject` extends `Observable`. If you want to expose api of `ReplaySubject` you can return it instead of `Observable`. As I understood the goal of the `getDog` to return a stream that emits `Dog|boolean` and `Observable` fits it well.

Comment: Yet, it does. I understand Thank you, you helped a lot!